# D3js - tspan update not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, tspan

Chrome is not rendering if I update tspan dynamically with text():

```
<html>
....
<text id="small-text" style="color: #FFFFFF" fill="white">
<tspan id="small-text-span1" style="font-size:18px;color:#FFFFFF;" ></tspan>
<tspan id="small-text-span2" style="font-size:18px;color:#FFFFFF;" ></tspan>
<tspan id="small-text-span3" style="font-size:18px;color:#FFFFFF;" ></tspan>
<tspan id="small-text-span4" style="font-size:18px;color:#FFFFFF;" ></tspan>
</tspan>
</text>
</html>


var i=0;
for(var key in data){
d3.select("#small-text-span"+i).text(data[key]);
i = i+1;
}
```

This is working fine in all teh browsers except chrome. If I comment this javascript line everyhting works fine on chrome.

Could you please tell me why it is not working on chrome? I cannot use any other tags except span.

Comment: It works fine if I add some text to the first tspan tag initially. Could anyone please tell me why?

Comment: Is your code placed in the document ready of jQuery?